# Mule4: Implementing parallel-foreach to query Saleforces using OffSet and LIMIT

Tags: salesforce, soql, mule4, parallel-foreach

I am dealing with a Salesforce Object that have more than 500'000 records.
I want to parallelize in batches the following query:

`Select Name from Account limit vars.queryLimit offSet vars.queryOfset`

For example if I have 2000 records, I could dived them in 4 parallel processes:

```
proc1: Select Name from Account limit 500 offSet 0
proc2: Select Name from Account limit 500 offSet 1000
proc3: Select Name from Account limit 500 offSet 1500
proc4: Select Name from Account limit 500 offSet 2000
```

How can I do that using parallel-foreach?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The [parallel foreach](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/parallel-foreach-scope) scope doesn't has that capability. Instead you couuld explore using a [Batch job](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/batch-processing-concept).